# DataTables not working when built for production

Tags: vue.js, datatables, vite

I'm using DataTables with Vue and Vite, which works flawlessly using `npm run dev`, however when building for production `npm run build`, no page where the DT is used, works. It throws an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'plugin-init')
```

The file is compiled and obfuscated and usually named style-`{random-identifier}`.js, however, sometimes it appears as `jquery.dataTables-{random-identifier}.js`.

Browsing through the file itself, this block in particular is throwing the error:

```
b(document).on("plugin-init.dt", function(e, r) {
    var a = new ae(r)
      , i = "on-plugin-init"
      , s = "stateSaveParams." + i
      , f = "destroy. " + i;
    a.on(s, function(p, v, m) {
        for (var _ = v.rowIdFn, C = v.aoData, S = [], L = 0; L < C.length; L++)
            C[L]._detailsShow && S.push("#" + _(C[L]._aData));
        m.childRows = S
    }),
    a.on(f, function() {
        a.off(s + " " + f)
    });
    var h = a.state.loaded();
    h && h.childRows && a.rows(b.map(h.childRows, function(p) {
        return p.replace(/:/g, "\\:")
    })).every(function() {
        ue(r, null, "requestChild", [this])
    })
});
```

This is a sample code how I use the DT:

```
<script setup>
import DataTable from 'datatables.net-vue3'
import DataTablesLib from 'datatables.net';

defineProps({
    Invoices: JSON,
});

const columns = [{data: 'id', title: 'No.'}];
</script>


<template>
           <DataTable
             :data="Invoices"
             :columns="columns"
           </DataTable>
</template>
```

This is the `vite.config.js` code:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'ziggy': '/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js',
            'ziggy-vue': '/vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/vue',
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
        nodePolyfills({
            // Whether to polyfill `node:` protocol imports.
            protocolImports: true,
        }),
    ],
    css: {
        postcss: {
            plugins: [tailwindcss],
        },
    },
    define: { global: "globalThis" }
});
```

I'm using Laragon v6.0 220916 as a server, vite v4.0, datatables.net v1.13.4, datatables.net-vue3 v2.0.

Is there any available command to at least trace such prod builds, pre-obfuscated, or what's causing it?

Comment: I started to suspect that it has to do with jQuery. Precisely, there could be a problem with integrating InertiaJS with jQuery when using VueJs + Vite. Only when building for production - otherwise the problematic line appears as `$(document).on("plugin-init.dt", function(e, r) {` instead "b" (or any other character when obfuscated), it appears "$".

Comment: So did you find the solution? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked on my local machine by installing a sample vue vite application. There was an issue with the dependencies version. I hope this answer can help.
So I updated the `Vue`, and `vite` packages

make sure we don't need to explicitly install `jquery` and `datatables.net` as these will come with the `datatables.net-vue3` package.

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.8",
    "datatables.net-bs5": "^1.13.8",
    "datatables.net-vue3": "^2.1.3",
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.0",
}
```